# NS_ERROR_FAILURE in SQLite insert

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax-error, nserror

I just bought a Kobo eReader which forces me to register at their website before the eReader functions. Seeing that I'm quite a privacy fundamentalist I refuse to register to read a couple books, so I went searching for an alternative. This brought me to [this blogpost](http://max.kellermann.name/tricks/kobo.html), which suggests to open the SQLite DB on the eReader and manually inserting a user with the following insert (formatted for readability):

```
INSERT INTO user (
    UserID
    ,UserKey
    ,UserDisplayName
    ,UserEmail
    ,___DeviceID
    ,HasMadePurchase
)
VALUES (
    ‘5b8b0d65-b50f-4460-b6df-aca5e64f4882’
    ,’626d73ed-8382-4c1d-9750-cfe741c6e773’
    ,’a_name’
    ,’an_email_address’
    ,’01:23:45:67:89:ab’
    ,’TRUE’
);
```

So I found the sqlite database and I ran the query, but I get the following error message

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT INTO user(UserID,UserKey,UserDisplayName,UserEmail,___DeviceID,HasMadePurchase) VALUES(‘5b8b0d65-b50f-4460-b6df-aca5e64f4882’,’626d73ed-8382-4c1d-9750-cfe741c6e773’,’a_name’,’an_email_address’,’01:23:45:67:89:ab’,’TRUE’);
[ unrecognized token: "4c1d" ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

I looked at the structure of the user table, which is (as you can see below), slightly different from the the query.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    UserID TEXT NOT NULL
    ,UserKey TEXT NOT NULL
    ,UserDisplayName TEXT
    ,UserEmail TEXT
    ,___DeviceID TEXT
    ,FacebookAuthToken TEXT                    <= missing from query
    ,HasMadePurchase BIT DEFAULT FALSE
    ,IsOneStoreAccount BIT DEFAULT FALSE       <= missing from query
    ,IsChildAccount BIT DEFAULT FALSE          <= missing from query
    ,PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
)
```

As you can see there are three columns in the db which are not in the query. I don't think that this is the source of the error though.

Does anybody know what the error means and how I can solve the error? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Would it not be simpler (and non-TOS violating) to create an account with a false identity / pre-paid credit card? Unless you're doing this as a personal challenge. :)

Comment: @bd33 - It is indeed the latter; a personal challenge.. :)

Comment: Based on the fact that the error it's throwing references the middle portion of a string... try double quotes ("") instead of singles ('')?

Comment: @bd33 - Awesome, that in combination with surrounding all column names with backticks (`) made it work and it now starts up. I now just have to find out how to add books to it without the Kobo software.. But thanks a million! (ps: if you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the single quotes on the VALUES section to double quotes - the error references the middle portion of your string.
In addition to that, surround the column values in backticks and then everything works.