# insert data to contacts2.db

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

Why error in `raw_contacts` ?

ERROR :

> SQLiteManager:
>   INSERT INTO "raw_contacts" VALUES(1,1,NULL,0,2,1,0,1,0,0,NULL,0,0,NULL,0,2147483647,'09999999999','09999999999',20,NULL,'0','09999999999','#',208,'09999999999','#',208,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); [ no such collation sequence: PHONEBOOK ]
>   Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>   Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

SQL statement for `INSERT` :

```
INSERT INTO "contacts" 
VALUES(1, 1, NULL, NULL,  NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2147483647, 1, '0r1-1224142414221E16121C1C', NULL, 1448202599930);

INSERT INTO "data" 
VALUES(1, NULL, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, '09999999999', '2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO "default_directory" 
VALUES(1);

INSERT INTO "phone_lookup" 
VALUES(1, 1, '09999999999', '5502681');

INSERT INTO "raw_contacts" 
VALUES(1, 1, NULL, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 2147483647, '09999999999', '09999999999', 20, NULL, '0', '09999999999', '#', 208, '09999999999', '#', 208, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO "search_index" 
VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, '09999999999');

INSERT INTO "visible_contacts" 
VALUES(1);
```

Help me please :((

Sorry.My English is not good.

structure raw_contacts :

```
CREATE TABLE raw_contacts 
(
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    account_id INTEGER REFERENCES accounts(_id),
    sourceid TEXT,
    raw_contact_is_read_only INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    dirty INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    deleted INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    contact_id INTEGER REFERENCES contacts(_id),
    aggregation_mode INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    aggregation_needed INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    custom_ringtone TEXT,
    send_to_voicemail INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    times_contacted INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    last_time_contacted INTEGER,
    starred INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    pinned INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 2147483647,
    display_name TEXT, display_name_alt TEXT,
    display_name_source INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    phonetic_name TEXT, phonetic_name_style TEXT,
    sort_key TEXT COLLATE PHONEBOOK,
    phonebook_label TEXT,
    phonebook_bucket INTEGER,
    sort_key_alt TEXT COLLATE PHONEBOOK,
    phonebook_label_alt TEXT,
    phonebook_bucket_alt INTEGER,
    name_verified INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    sync1 TEXT, sync2 TEXT, sync3 TEXT, sync4 TEXT 
)
```

Comment: Well, can you post the **table structure** for `raw_contacts`? Also: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the columns you want to insert into - that way, you can also spare yourself all those `NULL` in the `VALUES` - just define those columns you really want to insert a value into - and provide those values (and everything else is left NULL)

Comment: edit post, add structure raw_contacts

Comment: Made table structure **readable** ....

Answer (score 1):

This table requires that the application using it has defined a collation named "PHONEBOOK".

You have to either define this collation, or remove the COLLATE PHONEBOOK from the table definition and live with the different sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

Change the single quotes on the VALUES section to double quotes
See this link
[NS_ERROR_FAILURE in SQLite insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025578/ns-error-failure-in-sqlite-insert)